# Structure Group prefixes in RTL languages

Tags: web8, structuregroups, navigation

I am involved in creating of a website in Hebrew (and a corresponding publication for it in Tridion). The other publications for LTR websites are using number prefixes for the navigation and so should this one. When I tried to enter dummy content in Hebrew in the structure groups properties, I noticed that the number gets automatically pushed to the left side whatever I do. 
What I did was:

- copied text from a Word document where the number was on the right side and when I pasted it, it was pushed to the left
- typed the number first and then the text in Hebrew hoping it would be pushed to the right side, but it stayed on the left (unlike in a Word document)

Is this expected behavior? What are the best practices regarding the navigation for RTL languages in Tridion?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the user language and region preferences in the top right corner of your screen? If it's set to English/US you might see this behaviour.

Comment: Hi, @NickoliRoussakov! Thanks for the suggestion. I changed my regional settings to Hebrew, but no effect. I could not change my language to Hebrew (it is not listed as an option).